Why is ZFS having such an impact on my iMac?
I installed the OpenZFS on Mac v2.2.2 package for Big Sur 11.7.9, gave it access through the Security Preferences, and rebooted.
I used diskutil to erase an external SSD drive I'm testing with. When I erased the volume, I put Mac OS Extended on it.
I then created a single volume pool on the device.
zpool create -f mypool  /dev/disk6s2

I used -f because without it, it complained about the FS already there.
Everything seemed to go fine.
# zpool status mypool
  pool: mypool
 state: ONLINE
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    mypool      ONLINE       0     0     0
      disk6s2   ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

I then tried to copy a 20GB file on my internal drive I had handy using the Finder.
It started copying fine, but then, everything came to a screeching halt.
Most notably, my mouse was unresponsive. I'd move it and it would crawl across the screen. I noticed on the Activity Monitor that both the Read and Write speeds were getting slower and slower, from 100+MB/s down to below 20. After some very careful and patient mouse positioning, I managed to cancel the copy. CPU load was not particularly notable.
The machine went back to its normal responsiveness.
This machine is a 2020 Intel iMac with 72GB of RAM.
A while (year or so) ago I tried ZFS. That time, I created two partitions and tried to mirror them. But, again, performance was terrible. I thought it was because I mirrored to halves of the same physical drive (not a practical solution, but I was just playing around). But this time, it was the whole volume.
If it matters, I'm running a Logitech MX Master 3 keyboard and mouse.
Curious if anyone else has seen anything like this. ZFS is essentially unusable for me because of this.

Are you comfortable opening some shells and having an iostat and top going and repeating a much much smaller copy? You’ve got enough resources on that Mac to diagnose a performance problem if you start with smaller copies. I would also recreate your pool and make a filesystem with these settings before testing.
